# How do I reference the outer "$(this)" in jquery?

Tags: jquery, this

Let's say I have code like this:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + "_Suffix").livequery('click', function(){
        doSomething($(this));
    });
});
```

The `$(this)` that I pass to the `doSomething` function is what's in the *second* jquery parenthesis -  `$('#' + $(this).attr('id') + "_Suffix")`. How do I reference what's in the first parenthesis - what the original this referred to? ( `$('.myClass').each` )

I assume I could save it into a variable, and then use that variable:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
    outerThis = $(this);
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + "_Suffix").livequery('click', function(){
        doSomething($(outerThis));
    });
});
```

But is there any way to reference it without doing this?

Comment: Don't both $(this) represent the same DOM object?

Comment: @dennis - thanks for the formatting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put it in a separate variable:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
    var outer = $(this);
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + "_Suffix").livequery('click', function(){
        doSomething(outer);
    });
});
```

Also, `livequery` is deprecated; you should use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead.

Comment: oh, wow; so I answered myself in my question just now. There's no other way to do this?

Comment: @froadie: Correct, except that you need to declare the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the scope in local variable:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + "_Suffix").livequery('click', function(){
        doSomething($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: gosh, missed it by 10 seconds and you don't get any upvotes :-/ Thanks for responding so fast!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use local variable

```
 $('.myClass').each(function(){
    var myclassObj = $(this);
        $('#' + myclassObj.attr('id') + "_Suffix").livequery('click', function(){
            doSomething($(this));
        });
    });
```